# Confused about "Global" & "Nonlocal" code (PYTHON/TKINTER) (UnboundLocalError:)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am in the process of converting a shell only code to GUI.

My issue is that I have defined a variable within one def function and I want to run this variable in a second def function. I have attempted to make the variable global however I am still getting an error.

Below in include my code;
(please note the two def functions)

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import random
import sys
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Shanes Number Guessing Game")
window.geometry("600x500")

#GUI Image
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Python-Tkinter pics\\numberguess.png")
photo1 = tk.Label(image=logo)
photo1.image = logo
photo1.pack()

#score
tries = 0
wins = 0


#enter username
userNameLabel = tk.Label(window,text="please enter your name below")
userNameEntry = tk.Entry(window)
userNameLabel.pack()
userNameEntry.pack()


#GUI Buttons
enterGuessLabel = tk.Label(window, text="enter guess below")
enterGuessLabel.pack()

enterGuess =  tk.Entry(window)
guess = enterGuess
enterGuess.pack()


#random number 
rannum = random.randrange(1,100)
print (rannum)

#Throw dice
def throwDice():
    global diceResult
    global tries
    diceResult = random.randrange(1,6)
    print (diceResult)
    tries += diceResult                 #UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tries' referenced before assignment

                                        #diceResult is in a function
def takeGuess():
    global wins
    global losses
    global tries
    global diceResult
    count = diceResult   #NameError: name 'diceResult' is not defined
    while not count == 0:
        tries = diceResult  #NameError: name 'diceResult' is not defined
        if (enterGuess == rannum):
            print ("correct")
            wins += 1
            print (win)
            break
    
        else:
            print("incorrect")
            tries += 1
            count -= 1
                      

    #GUI Buttons
diceButton = tk.Button(window, text="roll dice", command=throwDice)
diceButton.pack()

guessButton = tk.Button(window, text="take guess", command=takeGuess)  #button will need a comand
inputGuess = guessButton
guessButton.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

When i action the program, the GUI opens. When I click on the GUI button called "diceButton" (that runs the command" throwdice") I gain the expected results in the shell.

However, when I click on the GUI "guessButton" (that runs the command "takeGuess") i receive the error "NameError: name 'diceResult' is not defined"

Shell output:

```
10
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\shane\source\repos\ICT30118 CertIII Assessment\ICT30118 CertIII Assessment\ICT30118_CertIII_Assessment.py", line 54, in takeGuess
    count = diceResult   #NameError: name 'diceResult' is not defined
NameError: name 'diceResult' is not defined
```

I have attempted to do some research on this issue, however i am still confused.
[https://medium.com/@vbsreddy1/unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value-in-python-e34e097547d6#:~:text=UnboundLocalError%3A%20local%20variable%20referenced%20before%20assignment%20in%20Python.,-VINTA%20BHARATH%20SAI&text=In%20Python%2C%20variables%20that%20are,unless%20explicitly%20declared%20as%20global](https://medium.com/@vbsreddy1/unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value-in-python-e34e097547d6#:%7E:text=UnboundLocalError%3A%20local%20variable%20referenced%20before%20assignment%20in%20Python.,-VINTA%20BHARATH%20SAI&text=In%20Python%2C%20variables%20that%20are,unless%20explicitly%20declared%20as%20global).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diceResult` isn't defined until you call `throwDice`. If you click on the "guess" button before clicking on the "roll dice" button, `diceResult` won't exist and you get the error in your question.

In other words, the problem isn't in *how* you define the variables as global, but rather *when* the variables are initially defined.

Comment: I just simply moved "diceResult" outside of the function and now I am getting progress, thanks for the assist.